# How to filter DataGridView results on the fly? (VB)

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView showing information stored in a database.

Say I have a Column for subjects (Maths, English and Science), how can I make it so the DataGridView will only show the subject I choose (preferably via a dropdown box). So if I have English selected in the dropdown box, it will only show the data entries that have Subject = English.

I'm pretty clueless so help is greatly appreciated, thanks.
(This is in VB)

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Basically, you want to query your database and filter your data based on the SelectedValue in the dropdownbox. If you google VB.Net and ADO.Net, you should find code to get you started. Then, you can post what you've tried here and someone can help you tweak your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on your dataview and showing that on the datagrid.

```
Dim view as new DataView //'Declare a new dataview
view.Table = someDataSet.Tables("Sometable") //'the table you're working with
view.RowFilter = "subject = 'English'" //'The filter as you were writing a where clause
someDatagridview.DataSource = view //'bind it to DGW
```