# Search rows on a data bounded DGV

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I tried this :

```
If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
        Me.PigletsBindingSource.Filter = "EN like " & txtSearch.Text.ToString() & " %"
    End If
```

Though it gives me an error of `Missing operand before 'Mod' operator`
What wrong?
I am working on a search engine for a bounded DGV because there is too many data to find just by scrolling down. Thanks

Comment: try with `Me.PigletsBindingSource.Filter = "EN like '[" & txtSearch.Text.ToString() & "]'%"`

Answer (score 1):

[from other post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348224/how-to-filter-datagridview-results-on-the-fly-vb)

```
Dim dv As New DataView
        dv.Table = MrlivestockDataSet.Tables("piglets")
        dv.RowFilter = "EN = '" & txtSearch.Text & "' "
        dgvReports.DataSource = dv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This Too:

```
Dim bs as  BindingSource = new BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource
bs.Filter = "EN = '" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

Comment: this did not solve the problem but I have it to working now. thanks